# Remove lines and variables in file using a regex (python)

Tags: python, regex, file

I have a file that I need to read. The file I'm reading is as follows:

```
module first(x,y,z);
   output x;
   input y;
   input [0:7] z;
# z is later used in the file and occurs more than twice
endmodule
.....
```

After reading the above file I need to look for any lines that follow the pattern of `input identifier;` or `input [digit:digit] identifier;` For that I have made a regular expression as follows:

`pattern = re.compile(r'(input)(\s*)(\[*\d*\d*\d*:*\d*\d*\d*\]*)(\s+)(\w+)')`

I then need to find the variable name (identifier). In the above example in `input y;` . I would need to find the `y`. If this variable occurs twice or less I need to remove it. So, if `y` occurred only twice in the file I would remove the `input y` line and `y` in the parenthesis. So the file would change to

```
module first(x,z);
   output x;
   input [0:7] z;
# z occurs more than twice in the file
endmodule
.....
```

The code I have written is as follows:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(input)(\s*)(\[*\d*\d*\d*:*\d*\d*\d*\]*)(\s+)(\w+)')
with open('filename' ,'r') as f:
   data = f.read()
result = re.search(pattern, data)
identifier = search_result.group(5)
```

The above code allows me to only get the first variable name in an input, in the file and that's it. I tried putting it in a **for loop** but that didn't work either.

After I find all the variable names declared as input I want to check if the variable name occurred twice or less in the file. If it occurs less than twice, then I would have to remove both it's declaration line as in `input y` and in parenthesis.

How would I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"If this variable occurs twice or less"_? You mean if there is only 1x or 2x `input y`, then you have to delete all occurrences of `y`? It would be better if you put an end to end example where a variable occurs less than twice and when a variable occurs more than 2x, and then the expected output.

Comment: for example, if in the file: `y` appears in the parenthesis, then `y `appears in the declaration `input y;` meaning in this case it occurred twice. Both the `y` in the parenthesis is removed and the `input y` is removed. Hence, y appeared twice in the file.

Comment: What if there's another `input y` in the next lines, should it be removed already too?

Comment: Hypothetically Yes, but that would not happen in any of the files I have. So, I don't have to take that into consideration

Comment: Also, `z` occurred twice too, why it isn't removed? Only `y` was removed in your example?

Comment: Apologies, I edited my post `z` would later appear more than twice in the file I just didn't include the entire file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pattern = re.compile(r'(input)(\s*)([*\d*\d*\d*:*\d*\d*\d*]*)(\s+)(\w+)')

If all we need is the variable name part in the end of the string, then we can skip already matching those brackets as we can just match the end part. Then, we also need another regex to match the `module` lines.

You can iterate over the file contents twice:

- first iteration to count the occurrences of the variable names with the `"input"` code
- then second iteration to delete/reconstruct the lines where the variable names with a count of less than or equal 2 exists in the line

```
from collections import Counter
import re

# Read the input file
with open('input.txt') as file_input:
    contents = file_input.readlines()

# Initialize the counters for the variable names declared in both the <input> and <module> lines
input_names = Counter()
module_names = Counter()

# Prepare the regex matchers to capture the variable names declared in both the <input> and <module> lines
input_re = re.compile(r"^.*input.*?(\w+);$")
module_re = re.compile(r"^module(.*?)\((.*)\);$")

# Iterate over each line in the file content to count all the variable names. No deletions yet, just counting.
for line in contents:
    if match := input_re.match(line):
        # If the line is an <input> line, extract and count the variable name.
        input_names[match.group(1)] += 1
    elif match := module_re.match(line):
        # If the line is a <module> line, extract and count the variable names separated by a comma.
        splits = match.group(2).split(',')
        module_names += Counter(splits)

# Get the names to delete, which are the variables in <input> that are only used once or twice.
names_to_delete = set()
for key in input_names:
    if input_names[key] + module_names.get(key, 0) <= 2:
        # So if the variable in <input> is only used twice or less, mark it for deletion.
        names_to_delete.add(key)

# Re-iterate over each line. This time, delete the variable names to be deleted.
contents_updated = ""
for line in contents:
    if match := input_re.match(line):
        if match.group(1) in names_to_delete:
            # If the line is an <input> line and contains the variable to delete, remove the whole line.
            line = ""
    elif match := module_re.match(line):
        # If the line is a <module> line, remove the variables that are to be deleted. Reconstruct the line without those variables.
        splits = match.group(2).split(',')
        line = module_re.sub(
            r'module\1(' + ",".join(filter(lambda value: value not in names_to_delete, splits)) + ");",
            line,
        )

    contents_updated += line

# Write the updated contents to a new file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file_output:
    file_output.write(contents_updated)

print("Deleted names:", names_to_delete)
```

**input.txt**

```
module first(x,y,z);
    output x;
    input y;
    input [0:7] z;
input [1:2] abc;
input [3:4] jkl;
module second(abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno);
    input mno;
module third(z,jkl);
module fourth(pq);
    input pq;
module fourth(rstu);
module fifth(def,x);
input v;
```

**output.txt**

```
module first(x,z);
    output x;
    input [0:7] z;
input [3:4] jkl;
module second(def,ghi,jkl);
module third(z,jkl);
module fourth();
module fourth(rstu);
module fifth(def,x);
```

Execution output:

```
Deleted names: {'pq', 'y', 'v', 'abc', 'mno'}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It fixes the issue that I was having. But, it removes the module's name. I still need the module's name in the file. So, it would be `module first (x,z)`

Comment: Ok I see. I updated the answer to also include the module names. Does it work on your side now?

Comment: When I ran it ,It keeps the module name `first`. But, now it keeps the `input y` line and the `y` in the parameters. So now, I'm getting `module first (x,y,z)` and the `input y` line is not removed

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the input.txt? I tried running the script in my answer now and it is already working. Maybe you could refresh the page and re-copy the code?

Comment: I refreshed, ran it again and the file does not change at all. I don't know why. Also, tried a different file did not change.

Comment: Are you looking at `input.txt`? Note that the code doesn't override that file, instead it writes to a new file `output.txt`. Did you check `output.txt`? The `output.txt` is the file that would contain the filtered out variables. Also, did you prepare the `input.txt` file? The script would look for the `input.txt` in the same folder as the script.

Comment: @AronChabane I added a screenshot of the files in my answer specifically this https://i.stack.imgur.com/doC5J.png which contains sample execution and the output. I hope it would be resolved on your end :)

Comment: Yes, I did all of that. I know what the issue is. It's when there is whitespace before `input` it does not work. I updated my question to reflect the whitespace before the variable names inside the body. Does that mean the regex should be updated?

Comment: Ahh okay. Yes the regex part must be changed slightly. Just add `.*` for `input_re`. I updated my answer to support this. Could you check?